# Does the word 'afternoon' need a preposition before, in the following context?

Tags: prepositions

Does the word 'afternoon' need a preposition before, in the following context?

> He reads books afternoon, usually.

Or it should be with 'in the':

> He reads books **in** the afternoon, usually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a preposition before. But

> He reads books afternoon**s**.

is OK (see [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/afternoons)), if a little terse or poetic.

You may need to clarify the sense of your sentence. Is the afternoon the time when he usually reads, or is reading what he usually does in the afternoon?

Comment: Note that "in the" would probably still be required here in British English.